# What's the simplest "unused" code that won't be optimized out?

Tags: c++, debugging, optimization

Very frequently, I want to test the value of a variable in a function via a breakpoint.  In many cases, that variable never actually gets referenced by any code that "does stuff", but that doesn't mean I don't still want to see it.  Unfortunately, the optimizer is working against me and simply removing all such code when compiling, so I have to come up with convoluted grossness to fool the compiler into thinking those values actually matter so they don't get optimized away.  I don't want to turn the optimizer off, as it's doing important stuff in other places, but just for this one block of code I'd like to temporarily disable it for the sake of debugging.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Code the produces *observable behavior* fits the requirements by definition. For example, `printf("")`.

Access to volatile variable also formally constitutes observable behavior, although I won't be surprised if some compilers still discarded "unnecessary" volatile variables.

For this reason, a call to an I/O function appears to be the best canditate to me.

Comment: Didn't know that "volatile" could be used that way - I thought it was just for things that could be altered in another thread, but I guess it makes sense - even though I'm not using threads here, the compiler couldn't know that.  I tried just printing the variables (via printf or cout), but the environment I'm in doesn't give me any console output.  (Old Xbox console)  I'll try volatile and see if that works.

Comment: @Darrel Hoffman: You said you needed a piece of code to put a breakpoint on. My empty `printf` serves exactly that purpose. Not to print anything, but just for breakpoints.

Comment: Yeah, you get a breakpoint, but the unused variables are still optimized out, so it doesn't help much.  I could of course print the variables (even though I'd never see the output), but the empty printf statement alone isn't all that useful.

Comment: Can you redirect stdout? i mean, can't you use fprintf(stderr, "my var = %d\n" , myVar); ?

if you can open a file somewhere, fprintf-ing to it can do the trick. or you know, print the value and break on the print, it shouldn't be optimized out...

Answer (score 1):

You can try "volatile" keyword. Some intro is at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volatile_variable .

Generally speaking, the volatile keyword is intended to prevent the compiler from applying any optimizations on the code that assume values of variables cannot change "on their own."

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of a trick I've used:

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    std::cout << "before\n";
    if (std::time(NULL) == 0) {
        std::cout << "This should not appear\n";
    }
    std::cout << "after\n";
}
```

The `time()` call should always return a positive value, but the compiler has no way of knowing that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
#pragma optimize("",off)
```

?

MSVS specific I think - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chh3fb0k(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You do not specify your compiler so I will just add here that I have been using the volatile specifier on any variables that I use specifically for debugging. In my compiler (Embarcadero RAD Studio C++ Builder) I have been using this for a couple of years and not once has the variable been optimized out. Maybe you don't use this compiler, but if you do I can say volatile has certainly always worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If the only purpose of the variable is to be viewed while in a breakpoint with a debugger, you can make the variable global. You could, for instance, maintain a global buffer:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
char dbg_buffer[512];
template <typename T>
void poke_dbg (const T &t) {
    memcpy(dbg_buffer, &t, sizeof(T));
}
#else
#define poke_dbg(x)
#endif
```

Then during debugging, you can inspect the contents of the dbg_buffer (with an appropriate cast if desired).